Probability of choosing k specific elements with different probabilities from n total elements
Here's a problem with a simple statement that I've had difficulty answering:
We have an assortment of $n$ elements. Let $A_i$ represent the probability of the $i$th element being picked. Now let's say we pick $k$ elements without replacement ($k \in [1,n]$).
After each pick, the probability of picking all elements not picked so far is scaled to account for the fact that we can't pick already picked elements.
So for example, if $n=3$ and $A_1=\frac{1}{2},A_2=\frac{1}{3},A_3=\frac{1}{6}$, and we picked item $1$ on the first turn, then $A_2 = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{2}{3}$ and $A_3 = \frac{\frac{1}{6}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{3}$ on the second turn.

What is the probability that a given element $i$ was picked, given that $k$ elements were picked?

Here's my attempt at a solution (and it may make the question make more sense):
The probability that a given element $i$ was picked is the sum of the probabilities that any group that contains $i$ was picked. For the sake of simplicity let's say $i = 1$ and let's consider the group of the first $k$ elements. The probability of selecting this group in ascending order (smallest to largest index) is:
$$
A_{1}\cdot \frac{A_{2}}{1-A_{1}}\cdot\frac{A_{3}}{1-A_{1}-A_{2}}\cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{A_{k}}{1-A_{1}-\ldots-A_{k-1}}
$$
But wait, this is just in ascending order. To get the probability of choosing this group in general we need to add the probability over all orderings. This is where I hit a wall. Consider the probability of choosing this group in reverse order (largest to smallest index):
$$
A_{k}\cdot \frac{A_{k-1}}{1-A_{k}}\cdot\frac{A_{k-2}}{1-A_{k}-A_{k-1}}\cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{A_{1}}{1-A_{k}-\ldots-A_{2}}
$$
Although the numerators of the two quantities are the same, we obviously get completely different stuff for the denominators. So the probability of choosing this specific group is:
$$
(A_1 \cdot A_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot A_k) \biggl(\text{sum of these rational expressions that subtract A terms from 1}\biggr)
$$
Not to mention, solving this addition gives the probability that 1 specific group is chosen. Now I would need to sum over all possible groups that include $i$ to get to the answer!
Am I completely on the wrong track or is there no way to say anything about that "sum of rational expressions"?
I've found that in the case of a group of size 2, with corresponding probabilities $A_i$ and $A_j$the sum equals:
$$
\frac{2-A_i-A_j}{(1-A_i)(1-A_j)}
$$
(this is quite easy to see)
But when I try to do the same with a group of size 3, say, it gets extremely complicated.
Any remedy/ideas?

Find the probability $i$ was NOT picked, and then subtract that probability from 1.0.

@DavidG.Stork hmm, I think I tried this but I also seem to get stuck. Obviously on the first pick you have probability $(1-A_i)$ of not choosing $i$. But after the first pick, your probability of not choosing $i$ is not $(1-A_i)$, but $(1-A_j - A_i)$, where $j$ is the state picked on the last turn. How do you get away from the fact that your chance of not picking $i$ changes dependent on what you chose before?

The only way you can not pick $i$ is to not pick it on the first try (eliminating one element).  Next not pick $i$ again, and again...  See?

@DavidG.Stork well, I get what you're saying (I think). But again the probability of not picking $i$ the second time is completely dependent on which non-$i$ element we picked the first time. So the probability is not $(1-A_i)^k$. In fact, if $k=n$ then the probability of not picking $i$ is $0$. So while I understand the sentiment of your comment, I don't see how it brings me farther than this point because each element is weighted differently.

I can give an example with 3 elements: let's say $A_1 = \frac{1}{2}, A_2 = \frac{1}{3}, A_{3} = \frac{1}{6}$. Let's say that $k = 2$, and we want to know the probability of not choosing item 1. On the first move, the probability of not picking it is obviously $1-A_1 = \frac{1}{2}$. But depending on which of item 2 and 3 we picked, the probability of not picking it on the second move is different. If we picked item 2 the first move, the probability is $\frac{\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{1}{4}$. If we had chosen item 3, the probability would be $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{5}{6}}=\frac{2}{5}$

The question as worded doesn't make much sense. The $A_n$ values are only strictly probabilities on the first draw. After one ball (say, $j$) is chosen, indeed $\sum_{n \ne j} A_n \ne 1$. Do you mean that after a ball is drawn, the probabilities are updated to the relative probabilities, excluding the drawn balls?

@K.Jiang Yes, That's what I mean. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

If your question is not clear, then you should edit it to make it so. Readers should not have to decipher comments to understand your question.

The problem is complicated, and I am not convinced that there is a straightforward, insightful answer in the general case. One way to go about it is with PIE (i.e., principle of inclusion and exclusion). Consider all permutations of the colors $\{1, \dots, n\}$; if we are drawing $k$, then we take the first $k$ elements of a selected permutation.
Fix $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ as the desired color. The probability that color $i$ ends up in the first $k$ entries of the permutation is the probability that color $i$ comes up somewhere before at least $n - k$ other elements in the permutation. So, for all combinations of $n - k$ colors disjoint from $i$ (combinations indexed by $r$, colors within the combination indexed by $r_j$: note that $r_j \ne i$ for each $j, r$), compute $\sum_r \frac{A_i}{A_i + \sum_{r_j} A_{r_j}}$, and multiply by $c_0 = 1$ to initialize a running sum. For each $m \in \{1, \dots, k - 1\}$, let $r$ index over all combinations of $n - k + m$ colors disjoint from $i$, compute $\sum_r \frac{A_i}{A_i + \sum_{r_j} A_{r_j}}$, multiply by
$$c_m = 1 - \sum_{l = 0}^{m - 1} c_l \binom{m + n - k}{m - l} = (-1)^m \binom{m + n - k - 1}{n - k - 1}$$
(I will leave this for you to show), and add to the running sum. The final sum is the desired probability.
When $n - k$ is small, the result is somewhat straightforward, if still not exactly intuitive. For example, when $n - k = 1$, we have $c_m = (-1)^m$: just an alternating sum. For the example you gave in the comments with $n = 3$ and $k = 2$, the probability that color $1$ is drawn is as follows:
$$P = \left( \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}} + \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}} \right) - \left( \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6}} \right) = \left( \frac{3}{5} + \frac{3}{4} \right) - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{17}{20}$$
which you can check via direct calculation.

Thanks for the answer. I see now that there doesn't seem to be a "nice" resolution, but this procedure makes a lot of sense conceptually. I felt like I was overcomplicating the problem but it kind of is just that complicated.

@CarlosRosales Great, glad to help!

In my opinion the problem has a conceptual flaw. The outcomes are not equally likely so in order to solve this problem you have to specify how the probabilities of the other outcomes are changed after one element has been eliminated.
Suppose there are 3 elements A, B, C. The probabilities are : $p(A)=0.1,\:p(B)=0.5,\:p(C)=0.4$. Imagine the first picked element is C, so we are left with A and B. Now what are the probabilities of A and B? It is simply not defined in the questions. For example if there was a public poll of 3 options and the outcomes had probabilities A, B, C to come first, but suddenly the C was removed from the poll, the people who would have voted for C, now can choose A or B. If all of them voted for A, the chances would be fifty-fifty.
You could assume they "scale", as in after C has been eliminated $p(A) = 0.1/0.6 = 1/6, \: p(B) = 0.5/0.6=5/6. $ Even in this interpretation you would still need to know all the elements that has been picked by the round $k$ as well as their order to calculate the probability that element $i$ has already been picked.

Thanks for the answer; my intent was what you state at the end: the probabilities "scale", i.e. they update to their relative probabilities excluding the already-drawn balls. I should have been clearer in this respect, but you're right: you need to know all elements picked by round k in order to calculate the probability.

Can I ask where you encountered this problem? Have you thought of it yourself or is there an application for which this is useful?

I've been trying to work out some theory about random variables that take on distributions of other random variables with certain probabilities. A practical example: a motorist gets into a severe accident with probability $p$ and a fender bender with probability $1-p$. Severe accidents have expectation $10k of claims with variance 1000 while fender benders have expectation $500 of claims with variance 400. What is the expectation and variance of the motorist's claims? I then generalized the approach to $n$ distributions, and then wondered about non mutually exclusive events, leading me here.

Well in the case of your original question, it is a rather complex problem. However it shouldn't be extremely difficult to write a program which computes (simulates the situation) the probability of $i$ appearing by the round $k$, considering we take every possible route (for all elements and their orders). You could then calculate the average probability of $i$ happening by the round $k$ which could yield informative results given the initial probabilities aren't too far apart.

Also, you probably know this, but if the probabilities were equal, you could just use hypergeometric distribution.
